# Python string search for multiple tab

Tags: python, string, tabs

I'm trying to identify if this exact following string is in a row:  /t/t}

for whatever reason, Pycharm marks the bracket the same color as the quotations, which leads me to think it's not picking up the bracket.

example:
if "/t/t}" in row:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python does recognize "/t/t". You can test it with the code bellow:

```
myString = 'lalala/t/t}lalala'

print ( "/t/t}" in myString)
```

The output will be True.